# STM32 Ethernet switch

Tags: ethernet

I'm pretty new to implementing this Ethernet stuff...

So, is there anyone who can recommend an Ethernet switch (3 port, 2 out and 1 for STM32)?

I have seen that you can use a W3150A and and then use the Microchip LAN9303 Ethernet switch but it doesn't seem very smart.

I am very fond of how much work to do on the software part, if I can use the Ethernet library that is delivered from ST (cubeMx) that will be great.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think you're going to find a smart 3 port switch at a reasonable price. Does it really need to be only 3 ports? What is your budget for such a switch.

Comment: The budget for the switch part is about 5-7UDS like:https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/microchip-technology/LAN9303-ABZJ/638-1082-ND/2166034

Comment: @Andy it's a surprisingly common use case - a rack mounted device which needs an Ethernet port on both the front a back panel.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [KSZ8863](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/KSZ8863) - depending on version it has one MII or RMII and two 10/100BASE-T/TX phys.

AFAIK it is supported by lwIP which is a go-to IP library in ST's ecosystem.